# C#. ASP.NET. Как работать с файлом в многопотоке?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть API контроллер и метод для загрузки файлов

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(IFormFile file)
{
    try
    {
        var upload = new FileUpload(HostingEnvironment);
        upload.Upload(file, folder);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { 
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
    }
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

И метод `Upload` внутри `FileUpload` :

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(jsonPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{  
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Files, Formatting.Indented);
    byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json);

    fs.Write(array);
}
```

Храню объекты в разных папках, в каждой из папок есть `json` файл с путями к файлу в этой папке.

Проблема в том если загружается больше одного файла - то я не совсем понимаю как заблочить и дождаться доступ к файлу, пока предыдущий поток не закончит работу. Если глянуть под дебагом - то они обращаются одновременно к каждой из строчек кода.
Пробовал блочить locker'ом, и тем что находил в интернете, но не особо помогало. Отправку файлов со стороны клиента я изменить не могу.

Было бы здорово узнать что можно еще попробовать сделать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1243358/373567 как-то так

Comment: Давайте уточним. Файлы загружаются разными клиентами - происходят несколько запросов одновременно. При этом может совпасть значение `jsonPath`. Так?

Comment: Ничего не понятно... В метод `Save` приходит один файл: `IFormFile file`. В методе `Upload` откуда-то берётся `Files` - судя по множественному числу - это коллекция файлов.

Comment: При создании `FileStream` можно указать параметр `FileShare.None` - это не даст обратиться к этому же файлу из других потоков (будет выбрасываться исключение).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov приходит один файл, да, но срабатывает этот контроллер столько раз - сколько файлов на него отправляется. Files можно не учитывать, просто без полного кода в методе может быть немного непонятно.

Проблему решил тем же локером, сделав его статичным

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. Почитайте про очереди. Вам нужно обрабатывать файлы по очереди. Если фронт высылает вам файлы одновременно. То получив файлы помещяйте их в очередь и обрабатывайте уже по очереди отдельным потоком. А потоук выславший вам файл пусть пришлет его но вы не должны его обрабатывать в потоке получивший его