# Нужно ли использовать оператор lock при записи файла в .net 5 api??? c# (код ниже)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp, core

```
public static async Task<string> SaveImageAsync(string base64)
{
    var normalizedBase64 = base64.Substring(base64.LastIndexOf(',') + 1);
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(normalizedBase64);
    var newFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + GetFileExtension(normalizedBase64);
    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", newFileName), bytes);
    return newFileName;
}
```

Comment: Если не в один и тот же файл писать, то вроде проблем не должно быть %)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по коду, каждый вызов метода будет работать с уникальным файлом. То есть разделяемых ресурсов здесь у вас нет.

А следовательно и не требуется обеспечение потокобезопасности.

---

Если потребуется синхронизировать доступ к общим файлам, то можно так:

- [Запись в файл из разных потоков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1243324/373567)